# Difference in foreign key lookup through object.fk.id and object.fk_id

Tags: python, django, performance

I have not found this question on SO.

Is there a speed difference between the following two variants of doing foreign key lookup in django's object model? I only need the foreign key.

```
class A(models.Model):
    x = models.PositiveIntegerField(null=True)

class B(models.Model):
    a = models.ForeignKey(A, null=True, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    y = models.PositiveIntegerField(null=True)

b = b.objects.last()
```

Which is faster or are they the same?

```
b.a_id
b.a.id
```

**edit:** Actually I think I can answer it myself... the second variant should be slower since it creates the whole object from the db, right?

Comment: There is no lookup for `fk_id`, since that is simply a *column* (a column stored in the database).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Simply: yes, there is a definite difference, and `b.a_id` is faster than `b.a.id`.

The latter retrieves the entire `a` object from the database as an additional query.
(You can save that query by adding `.select_related('a')`, but doing `.a.id` instead of `.a_id` is still unnecessary.)

Answer (score 1):

> Is there a speed difference between the following two variants of doing foreign key lookup in django's object model? I only need the foreign key.

Yes the `fk_id` is **stored in the database**. By default (that is if you do not `.defer(..)` that field, one way or another), it is loaded when the query is materialized (for example the object is loaded).

`.fk_id` this does *not* require extra querying. Whereas `.fk` is, unless you load it through `.select_related(..)` or `.prefetch_related(..)`, will require extra querying. Relations (like a foreign key relation) are loaded *lazily*: if you query `self.fk.id`, you will first fetch `.fk` resulting in an extra query, and then you will fetch the `.id` from that object (which takes *no* extra queries).